# How to scrape view count on Youtube video with Jsoup?

Tags: java, eclipse, youtube, jsoup

I am trying to get the view count of a youtube video in Jsoup. I started by getting the title which worked well but am having trouble getting the view count which is in a span class.

Here is my code so far:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class HigherOrLowerYoutube {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
          Document doc = 
          Jsoup.connect("https://www.youtube.com/watchv=omlFsLz2WKM").get();
          println(doc.title());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void println(String string) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

}

Comment: You can't do it with Jsoup - the data is loaded dynamically with javaScript. Try to use something like phantomJS.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
System.out.println(doc.select(".watch-view-count").first().text());
```